# Single form to create multiple SKU's from user options

Tags: ms-access-2016

This is complicated and difficult to explain, but here it goes. I have created a db that works just fine. It is a time saver, but not efficient for the user. I have a form for the merchandise where the user selects a paper type from a combobox. They are presented with two choices. They must also select a print size from another combobox. They are presented with 5 choices. I have VBA code that creates a SKU number based on these selections.

An art piece can use both paper types and be available in all 5 sizes. What I am trying to figure out is how I can offer all the possible choices on this form, allow the user to select options for that piece. As an example, the user chooses both paper types and all print sizes. This would create 10 SKU numbers for one art piece. Below is a copy of the form in it's current view:

[image]

Is this possible to do from one form? If so, how can this be accomplished in the most efficient way? I feel that it can. In VBA, this would be an IF nest nightmare, especially when concatenating the SKU variables. Either Select statements or another method that I am unaware of, could be the solution.

Thanks in advance for any and all suggestions and assistance.

EDIT: I hope this helps clarify. I would prefer to use this form

[image]

to complete the task. The checkboxes are not in an option group so they could all be checked if the user requires it. For the purposes of this question, let's assume the user has checked all the boxes. This would equal 10 total combinations.

I run this sub to generate a SKU based on the paper type and the print size:

```
Private Function UpdateArtwork()

Me.MerchandiseSKU = Me.cboArtworkID_A5A.Column(5) & _
Me.cboPrintTypeID_A5A.Column(2) & Me.cboPaperTypeID_A5A.Column(0) & _
Format(Me.cboPrintSizeID_A5A.Column(0), "00")

Call UpdateArtworkPic

End Function
```

I am trying to figure out how to write the code for the new form that allows all 10 SKU numbers to be generated and create 10 new records for Artwork_ID (Artwork table).

Comment: Unless I am missing something here, whilst there are 10 **possible** combinations of paper type/size, they will only be selecting one of these? So your SKU would be just concatenating the selected SKU paper part to the selected SKU paper size?

Comment: @Applecore Yes, there are 10 possible combinations. Currently each form is only allowing me to create 1 of these combinations at a time. But there may be multiple sizes available. Each variation of paper type or print size would require the user to fill out this form for each one. I am trying to get the form to allow all combinations (maybe using checkboxes for each choice?) and somehow get a unique SKU number for each combination. I understand that this will create (up to) 10 records, and that is what I am expecting. But I am trying to avoid filling out the form 10 times.

Comment: Continued... In the end, if all 10 combinations are chosen, there would be 10 Merchandise SKU numbers for each Artwork_ID (10 total records). I already have VBA to run the concatenation for the SKU's successfully. I hope this clarifies my intent for this form.

Comment: @Applecore - I liked your answer and understood the concept. However, I could not get it to work correctly for me. It is probably something I am missing. At any rate, does it make a difference if I say that using a subform is not necessary. What approach would work best to create the MerchandiseSKU's for each of the 10 combinations and create 10 new records associated to the Artwork_ID, automatically, when the user is adding the artwork as Merchandise on the form (from above)? At this point, should I create a new question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best way of doing this would be to create a new table, called tblArtworkSKU, which has the following fields:

- ArtworkSKU_ID - Autonumber, primary key;
- Artwork_ID - number, foreign key from the Artwork table;
- PrintSize_ID - foreign key from the PrintSize table;
- PrintType_ID - foreign key from the PrintType table;
- ArtworkSKU - text.

You would then create a small continuous form based on this table, with PrintSize_ID and PrintType_ID selected through combo boxes. When you place this form onto the main form that you have, Access should automatically let you join on Artwork_ID to create a one-to-many relationship.

You could then use the AfterUpdate events of each combo box to create the SKU.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks. I will work on this and let you know how it turns out. This seems like a good approach.